# Gatling synchronous Http request/response chain

Tags: synchronous, gatling

I have implemented a chain of executions and each execution will send a HTTP request to the server and does check if the response status is 2XX. I need to implement a synchronous model in which the next execution in the chain should only get triggered when the previous execution is successful i.e response status is 2xx. 
Below is the snapshot of the execution chain.

```
feed(postcodeFeeder).
     exec(Seq(LocateStock.locateStockExecution, ReserveStock.reserveStockExecution, CancelOrder.cancelStockExecution,
     ReserveStock.reserveStockExecution, ConfirmOrder.confirmStockExecution, CancelOrder.cancelStockExecution)
```

Since gatling has asynchronous IO model, what am currently observing is the HTTP requests are sent to the server in an asynchronous manner by a number of users and there is no real dependency between the executions with respect to a single user.

Also I wanted to know for an actor/user if an execution in a chain fails due the check, does it not proceed with the next execution in the chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is no real dependency between the executions with respect to a single user

No, you are wrong. Except when using "resources", requests are sequential for a given user. If you want to stop the flow for a given user when it encounters an error, you can use [exitblockonfail](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.2/general/scenario.html#exitblockonfail).

Comment: In a given execution chain where there is a check in each step in the execution does gatling wait for the response before sending the next one in the chain?

so in the code example that I had mentioned does the confirmStockExecution wait for the response of reserveStockExection as the reserveStockExecution might fail due to its check and I do not want the confirmStockExecution to be executed before receiving the response?

Comment: Basically what I wanted to achieve is something like

if(reserveStockExecution is successful)
       proceed with ConfirmStockExecution
            if(confirmStockExecution is successful)
                 proceed with CancelStockExecution

Comment: @slandelle any ideas on how to wait for a response before sending a next request in the chain ?

Comment: When the server throws an error back then chain does not break/exit automatically and gatling was continuing with the next request in the chain. So I have added exitBlockOnFail to break the chain explicitly to mimic the nested if logic that I needed. Thanks to Stephane Landelle.

Answer (score 1):

Gatling does not consider the failure response from the previous request before firing next in chain. You may need to cover the entire block with exitBlockOnFail{} to block the gatling to fire next.